# Mode of dirichlet distribution with parameters between 0 and 1

Tags: dirichlet-distribution

I have a dirichlet distribution with three dependent variables.What is the range in which the dirichlet parameters (alphas) should lie?                                                  I read in a reference only a condition near the pdf of dirichlet distribution  that alphas must be greater than 0. Is it correct?
I have alpha1=1.266, alpha 2 = 0.386, and alpha 3 = 0.4935.                                                       alpha 1 + alpha 2 + alpha 3 = 2.1455.                                    The mode of first variable is negative (since k =3 and 2.1455 is less than 3) and so the mode of other two variables becomes positive. But when they are added it sums to 1. Is it valid to get a negative mode for the first variable?

Comment: Where do you get this information?  Obviously the mode cannot be negative, since the variable values must all lie between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Since some $\alpha_i$'s are less than $1$, the mode is achieved when either the second or the third variable go to zero, with a value of $+\infty$.

Comment: Value of each variable lies between 0 and 1. I have three observations for each variable. For var1- (0.2, 0.75 and 0.82). For var 2 -  (0.2, 0.22 and 0.12). For var3 - (0.6, 0.03 and 0.06). Each set of observations sums to 1. For var 1, I estimated the alpha as 1.266 by the method of moments given by "A. Narayanan,1992, A note on parameter estimation in the multivariate beta distribution".Then I found dirichlet mode for var 1. But I get negative mode as the denominator(2.1455 - 3)is negative. I am confused where I go wrong. I believe the equation given in the reference to estimate alphas.

Comment: @AnaghaRaveendran It would be helpful if you can add more details in your question. You mention that var1, var2 and var3 are drawn from Dirichlet distribution with different hyper-parameters i.e. alpha. But then you estimate alpha using MOM?

Comment: The three variables and their three set of observations  are dependent to each other and it constitute my prior data to do the bayesian analysis. As suggested my project co-guide, I fit dirichlet distribution to this data. Then I combined it with multinomial likelihood data (x1,x2 and x3) and derived posterior distribution of Dirichlet form. In order to find posterior parameters  (alphas +x's) I used MOM to estimate alphas from prior distribution. Then I need to find  'posterior mode'. I got the 'negative mode' for the prior distribution when I simply tried to find 'prior mode'!.